# Playing Video on iPhone simulator with MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController to play video. I have added following piece of code, However its not playing. View is presenting with black screen and hiding immediately without playing.

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController  *moviePlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/gui_test/Desktop/273_0.mp4"]];
    moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES; 
    moviePlayerVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerVC];
    [moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer play];
```

Am I need to do anything more to play a mp4 file Note: I am trying in simulator. Is it possible to play a (.mp4) file in Simulator.

Comment: You can't access files outside the sandbox. Use a file in the app bundle or the app's documents directory.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I have copied the file into documentsDirectory and tried with replacing the path. It showing only black screen. Any Idea?

Comment: Could you post the updated code?

Comment: @CarlVeazey  NSURL *loc_url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/gui_test/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/96C4CA5F-E308-4F3D-BF63-EEE061E7A80D/Documents/cmpny/273/273_0.mp4"]; I am getting Null url here. This may be the problem. I have copied the document path here,     Is it OK.

Comment: If you hard-coded that into your app, that's not the way to do it. Why don't you start by just adding the movie to your xcode project, and then use the NSBundle `urlForResource:withExtension:subDirectory`  method to get the URL for your movie. Then see if it plays.

Comment: @As per my spec, its like a video message received from other, its not a single file, so all the cases it should work, I can't add any particular file for my case. I have a path , in that path, file may be many, depends on name I have to play the file. And I am hot coded just for testing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16179/discussion-between-carl-veazey-and-user1587011)

Answer (score 0):

I have  used  MPMoviePlayerController instead of MPMoviePlayerViewController:

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:songUrl];
[[self.moviePlayer view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[moviePlayer.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];   
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
```

Try this this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :) , and I guess it supports .mov files only and your video isn't playing cause its mp4

```
NSString*thePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL*theurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:thePath];
NSLog(@"the url= %@",theurl);

moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
[moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES]; 
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```